# Slice consecutive rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Consider this df:

```
   col1     
0   3   
1   4 
2   11
3   12
4   13
5   23
6   25
7   26
8   27
```

Is there an easy and short way to slice/group the consecutive rows, without looping? Or is a loop necessary? I would like to achieve an output like this:

```
list_of_consc_rows = [(3,4),(11,12,13),(23),(25,26,27)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate `tuple`s by helper `Series` created by compare difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)for not equal `1` and cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
L = df.groupby(df['col1'].diff().ne(1).cumsum())['col1'].agg(tuple).tolist()
print (L)
[(3, 4), (11, 12, 13), (23,), (25, 26, 27)]
```

Comment: Just. Beautiful. Thanks so much for the very fast reply !!